# Ebean orm cache

Tags: java, scala, orm, ehcache, ebean

I recently started using ebean orm cache for L2 caching SQL database. All works fine, but one of the problems I have encountered is that when a query is executed and an empty result set is returned, that DB response is not cached.

My question is whether it is done on purpose or whether it is a missing functionality in ORM Cache?

Some example of the response which is not cached:
    Ebean.find(User.class)
        .setUseQueryCache(true)
        .where()
        .eq("age", 20)
        .findList()

If the returned list is empty, the response is not cached.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please provide some code examples for us to help you

Comment: Added the code, thanks